MY Core 2 Q 9650 max frequency show on 2.70 GHZ (MAX frequency is 3.00GHZ) on windows 10
i have Q9650 on P5K-E and windows 10 home on my Rig. when i check task manager --> cpu monitor: max count is 2.70 GHZ but this model support 3.00GHZ .Can't Windows 10 use the full power of the processor or is the processor not compatible with this operating system? (I also updated the BIOS to the latest version)

Your CPU was discontinued many years before Windows 10.
